# Ordinal number to words in Python

Tags: python

## The problem

The input is a sentence containing words, numbers and ordinal numbers such as `1st`, `2nd`, `60th` and etc.

The output should contain only words. For example:

- `1st` → `first`
- `2nd` → `second`
- `60th` → `sixtieth`
- `523rd` → `five hundred twenty-third`

## What I have tried

`num2words` converts the numbers to words. But it does not work for ordinal terms such as `1st`, `2nd`, `60th` and etc.

## The question

How is possible to use python to turn ordinal numbers into words?

Comment: The [pypi listing for `num2words`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) suggests using `ordinal=True`, with `num2words(42, ordinal=True)` returning `forty-second`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the ordinal endings from the strings:

```
import re

re.findall('\d+', stringValue)
```

and then use

```
num2words(foundInteger, ordinal=True)
```

Comment: I'd not quite understood this part of the question, you've got it there. A couple of things I would say, though, is that 1) you don't define `foundInteger` in your answer and 2) you may need to wrap the results of your regex as an `int` to get `num2words` to work properly

Answer (score 10):

With `num2words`, you should be using `ordinal=True` to get the output you desire, as noted in its [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words):

```
from num2words import num2words

print(num2words(1, ordinal=True))
print(num2words(2, ordinal=True))
print(num2words(60, ordinal=True))
print(num2words(523, ordinal=True))
```

prints:

```
first
second
sixtieth
five hundred and twenty-third
```

Answer (score 6):

### The entire solution

```
import re
from num2words import num2words


def replace_ordinal_numbers(text):
    re_results = re.findall('(\d+(st|nd|rd|th))', text)
    for enitre_result, suffix in re_results:
        num = int(enitre_result[:-len(suffix)])
        text = text.replace(enitre_result, num2words(num, ordinal=True))
    return text


def replace_numbers(text):
    re_results = re.findall('\d+', text)
    for term in re_results:
        num = int(term)
        text = text.replace(term, num2words(num))
    return text


def convert_numbers(text):
    text = replace_ordinal_numbers(text)
    text = replace_numbers(text)

    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert convert_numbers('523rd') == 'five hundred and twenty-third'
```

Comment: Super reponse. 
Would just use `num = int(enitre_result[:-len(suffix)])`

Answer (score 0):

for numbers to ordinal values from 1-12, not sure how to do it the "shorter" way but this way uses basic python functions :)

```
def integerToOrdinal(x):
if x == 1
 ordinal = "first"
if x == 2:
    ordinal = "second"
if x == 3:
    ordinal = "third"
if x == 4:
    ordinal = "fourth"
if x == 5: 
    ordinal = "fifth"
if x == 6: 
    ordinal = "sixth"
if x == 7: 
    ordinal = "seventh"
if x == 8: 
    ordinal = "eigth"
if x == 9: 
    ordinal = "ninth"
if x == 10: 
    ordinal = "tenth"
if x == 11: 
    ordinal = "eleventh"
if x == 12: 
    ordinal = "twelfth"
return ordinal

x = int(input())
result = integerToOrdinal(x)
print(result)
```

Comment: This is doing it manually, there might be a library somewhere that does it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_suffix(num: int) -> str:
  last_two_digits = num % 100
  last_digit = num % 10

  suffix = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}.get(last_digit, 'th')
  if last_two_digits in [11, 12, 13]: suffix = "th"
  return suffix


def ordinal_to_english(o_num: int) -> str:
  if not isinstance(o_num, int) or o_num < 0:
    return "Error: input must be a positive integer"

  # Spelling of numbers less than 20
  spelling = {
    1: "fir",
    2: "seco",
    3: "thi",
    4: "four",
    5: "fif",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eigh",
    9: "nin",
    10: "ten",
    11: "eleven",
    12: "twelf",
    13: "thirteen",
    14: "fourteen",
    15: "fifteen",
    16: "sixteen",
    17: "seventeen",
    18: "eighteen",
    19: "nineteen"
  }

  # Spelling of multiples of 10
  tens_root = {
    2: "twen",
    3: "thir",
    4: "for",
    5: "fif",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eigh",
    9: "ninet"
  }

  # Spelling of multiples of 100
  hundreds_spelling = {
    1: "hundred",
    2: "two hundred",
    3: "three hundred",
    4: "four hundred",
    5: "five hundred",
    6: "six hundred",
    7: "seven hundred",
    8: "eight hundred",
    9: "nine hundred"
  }

  # Get the last two digits and the last digit of the number
  last_two_digits = o_num % 100
  last_digit = o_num % 10
  tens = last_two_digits // 10
  hundreds = o_num // 100  # adjust later for larger numbers

  if last_two_digits > 19:
    root = tens_root[tens]

  if 0 < last_two_digits < 20:
    ending_ordinal = spelling[last_two_digits] + get_suffix(last_two_digits)
  elif last_two_digits == 0:
    ending_ordinal = hundreds_spelling[hundreds] + 'th'
  elif last_digit == 0:
    ending_ordinal = root + "tieth"
  else:
    ending_ordinal = spelling[last_digit] + get_suffix(last_digit)
    compound_ordinal = root + "ty-" + ending_ordinal

  if o_num < 100:
    if 0 < last_two_digits < 20 or last_digit == 0:
      return ending_ordinal
    else:
      return compound_ordinal
  else:
    if 0 < last_two_digits < 20:
      return hundreds_spelling[hundreds] + " and " + ending_ordinal
    elif last_two_digits == 0:
      return ending_ordinal
    else:
      return hundreds_spelling[hundreds] + " and " + compound_ordinal
```